# How to put a wordcloud in a grob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid, word-cloud

I've created a simple wordcloud:

```
require(wordcloud)    
words <- c('affectionate', 'ambitious', 'anxious', 'articulate', 'artistic', 'caring', 'contented', 'creative', 'cynical', 'daring', 'dependable', 'easygoing', 'energetic', 'funny', 'generous', 'genuine', 'goodlistener', 'goodtalker', 'happy', 'hardworking', 'humerous', 'impulsive', 'intelligent', 'kind', 'loyal', 'modest', 'optimistic', 'outgoing', 'outrageous', 'passionate', 'perceptive', 'physicallyfit', 'quiet', 'rational', 'respectful', 'romantic', 'shy', 'spiritual', 'spontaneous', 'sweet', 'thoughtful', 'warm')
freqs <- c(134, 53, 0, 5, 0, 247, 0, 78, 0, 0, 134, 178, 79, 344, 63, 65, 257, 0, 109, 113, 0, 0, 107, 51, 199, 24, 67, 232, 0, 109, 24, 28, 29, 2, 105, 70, 0, 35, 64, 156, 66, 45)
wordcloud(words, freqs)
```

I would like to put this into a "grob" so that I can arrange it with several other plots using `grid.arrange()` in the `gridExtra` package:

```
require(ggplot2)
p1 <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), colour = runif(10))
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, my.wordcloud)
```

I understand that my wordcloud must be a "grob" to do this, but I don't understand how to make this so. I tried using the `grob()` function in the `gridExtra` package, but this didn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this is of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window/14125768#14125768

Comment: the plot method for wordcloud uses base graphics, not grid graphics (therefore no grob can encapsulate the drawing, or it would have to be written from scratch). Your best bet is to follow the examples of the gridBase package.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253765/geom-wordcloud-is-this-a-pipe-dream

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It shouldn't be that difficult to adapt the code in `wordcloud` to construct the data need to fill in a text.grob in grid. The `wordcloud` code sends x, y, text and rot values to the base `text` function after a window with limits of 0,0 and 1, 1 is specified.

I needed to add this before the for-loop:

```
textmat <- data.frame(x1=rep(NA, length(words)), y1=NA, words=NA_character_, 
                       rotWord=NA, cexw=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

This at the end of the for-loop:

```
 textmat[i, c(1,2,4,5) ] <-  c(x1=x1, y1=y1, rotWord=rotWord*90, cexw = size[i] )
 textmat[i, 3] <- words[i]
```

And needed to amend the call to `.overlap`, because it is apparently not exported:

```
if (!use.r.layout) 
         return(wordcloud:::.overlap(x1, y1, sw1, sh1, boxes))
```

And I returned it invisibly after the loop was complete:

```
return(invisible(textmat[-1, ]))  # to get rid of the NA row at the beginning
```

After naming it wordcloud2:

```
> tmat <- wordcloud2(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62))
> str(tmat)
'data.frame':   61 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x1     : num  0.493 0.531 0.538 0.487 ...
 $ y1     : num  0.497 0.479 0.532 0.475 ...
 $ words  : chr  "b" "O" "M" ...
 $ rotWord: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cexw   : num  0.561 2.796 2.682 1.421 ...

draw.text <- function(x,y,words,rotW,cexw) {
     grid.text(words, x=x,y=y, rot=rotW, gp=gpar( fontsize=9*cexw)) }

for(i in 1:nrow(tmat) ) { draw.text(x=tmat[i,"x1"], y=tmat[i,"y1"], 
                                    words=tmat[i,"words"], rot=tmat[i,"rotWord"], 
                                    cexw=tmat[i,"cexw"]) }
```

As suggested:

```
 with(tmat, grid.text(x=x1, y=y1, label=words, rot=rotWord, 
                      gp=gpar( fontsize=9*cexw)) }  # untested
```

Comment: Where does the magic number '9' in fontsize=9*cexw come from?

Comment: I'm just converting from cex to font sizes. Choose a different size as your default if you desire.

Comment: arguments to textGrob are vectorised, so you could do without the last for loop and return a single textGrob.

Comment: Excellent idea. I was mostly using it as a proof of concept. I wasn't sure I could get vectorized behavior out of the gpar call, but if you say so.

Comment: Many thanks! This does exactly what I need it to. Instead of plotting with grid.text at the end however, I used ggplot2 since all of the other things I am going to arrange with it are ggplot2 objects as well: `ggplot(tmat, aes(x=x1, y=y1, label=words, angle=rotWord, size=cexw))+
  geom_text()+
  labs(x='', y='')+
  guides(size=F)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border=element_blank())`

Comment: Internally ggplot uses grid graphics, and is probably creating those text labels as grobs from grid.text. Are we one step away from +geom_wordcloud(...)?

Comment: @Spacedman `stat_cloud` maybe? BTW @morberg , you can use grid.arrange with a textGrob: `grid.arrange(qplot(1,1), textGrob("hi"))`

Comment: @morberg I am following your approach above ... what if `F` in the  `guides(size=F)`?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `gridBase` package but with a clever viewport. here I am using `vpStack` to get the good dimensions.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
wordcloud(words, freqs)
plot.new()              
vps <- baseViewports()
p <- qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), colour = runif(10))
print(p,vp = vpStack(vps$figure,vps$plot))
```

[image]

**EDIT** Use `knitr` if you want just to generate a pdf.

Another option if you want just to create a pdf you can use `Knitr`. Mixing grid and base graphics is really simple. Latex will do the job for you. Fo example, the above result can be obtained by this chunk.

```
<<mixgridwithggplot, fig.show='hold',out.width='.5\\linewidth'>>=
wordcloud(words, freqs)
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), colour = runif(10))
@
```

I am pretty sure that `knitr` can create the png of the 2 plots in a single png behind the code.