# How do I create a continuous density heatmap of 2D scatter data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can generate a density plot of 1D data with:

```
qplot(mydatapoints, geom='density')
```

I've also seen plenty of examples of heatmap grids, but these are more akin to histograms for 1D data in that data goes into discrete buckets instead of showing a smooth curve.

Can I plot something similar to the 1D density but for 2D data, with (say) something like hue/saturation/lightness to represent the density?

Comment: Or `stat_density2d`? Like [this](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_density2d.html)?

Comment: `smoothScatter()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076370/most-underused-data-visualization/7065171#7065171

Comment: Another option is `hexbin` (this is the name of both a package and a function)

Comment: `kde2d` from the MASS package plus `filled.contour` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you want a 2D density estimate, which is implemented by `kde2d` in the `MASS` package.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000),y=rnorm(10000))
```

via `MASS` and base R:

```
k <- with(df,MASS:::kde2d(x,y))
filled.contour(k)
```

via `ggplot` (`geom_density2d()` calls `kde2d()`)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_density2d()
```

I find `filled.contour` more attractive, but it's a big pain to work with if you want to modify anything because it uses `layout` and takes over the page layout. Building on Brian Diggs's answer, which fills in colours between the contours: here's the equivalent with different alpha levels, with transparent points added for comparison.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  stat_density2d(aes(alpha=..level..), geom="polygon") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(limits=c(0,0.2),breaks=seq(0,0.2,by=0.025))+
  geom_point(colour="red",alpha=0.02)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Any ideas if the data is more sparse than this? I'm getting small patches in some places but no coverage in others.

Comment: You might be able to increase the smoothing parameter of the kernel density estimator.

Answer (score 9):

Combining two other answers (one pointing to `geom_density2d` and one giving sample data and `scale_colour_gradient`):

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000),y=rnorm(10000))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
    stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="green")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also `scale_colour_gradient()`

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000),y=rnorm(10000))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=y)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```