# R, ggplot - Density plot shows gaps

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I've been encountering some sort of bug when trying to plot a 2d density plot using ggplot2's function stat_density2d. When I only try to plot the outlines for the graph it seems to work fine:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x_loc, y=y_loc)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..))
```

However when I try to fill in the layers using geom = "polygon"

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x_loc, y=y_loc))+stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

I get this:

[image: Filled in]

This looks like it is giving geometry errors for some reason, but I'm not sure why. I've tried to work around this but I can't seem to find a solution. I've updated my R version and all my packages but it doesn't fix it.

As a reproducible example:

```
matrix = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,
3,1,2,3,1,2,3,18,12,20,24,22,35,18,12,19,20,5,16,11,7,10,5,1,3), nrow = 18)

ggplot(as.data.frame(matrix), aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + 
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

Which has the similar problems, for instance on the sides and on the top and bottom:

[image: Example output]

If anybody could help me with this that would be great, have stuck at this for several hours now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36456535/324364) question help?

Comment: Your reproducible example does not seem to reproduce for me -- something wrong with the step in which you create the matrix!

Comment: @user2728808 Apologies, I forgot to add the nrow parameter. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @joran Thanks increasing the limits does fix the weird gaps. However now my plot is way bigger than I want it to be. Is there a way where the polygons are plotted nicely but the plot is till within the limits I want them to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in @joran's comment, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456535/ggplot2-stat-density2d-produces-strange-triangles) seems to be of a similar ilk. The default clipping values seem to be causing the problem. The following works for me:

```
library(ggplot2)

matrix = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,
3,1,2,3,1,2,3,18,12,20,24,22,35,18,12,19,20,5,16,11,7,10,5,1,3), nrow = 18)

ggplot(as.data.frame(matrix), aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + 
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")+ 
lims(x = c(-1,8),y = c(-.25,4.25))
```

Comment: Thanks! that does fix the initial problem. However now the plot isn't in the dimensions I want it to be anymore. Is there anyway to have the polygons show correctly and have the dimensions I want them to be?

Comment: I guess you could just manually adjust the ``lims`` values to get the desired result? Otherwise, not sure I'm afraid!

Comment: The problem here is that when I adjust the `lims` values to the desired numbers, the polygons don't display properly. Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: @NilsMackay you can add `coord_cartesian()`