# calendar heat map tetris chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076370/most-underused-data-visualization) and I fell a little in love with the calendar heat map with Tetris-style month breaks.

However, the `ggplot` example doesn't implement the Tetris breaks, which are arguably the best part.

So, FTFY, [gist here](https://gist.github.com/dvmlls/5f46ad010bea890aaf17):

[image: results]

The procedure for this is:

1. create appropriate Tetris breaks for your data
2. `left_join` your data to the Tetris breaks created in (1)
3. pump the above through `ggplot` with some specially crafted `geom`s

The methodology for (1) is reasonably straightforward, implemented in the `calendar_tetris_data(...)` function in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dvmlls/5f46ad010bea890aaf17), though it would be nice to make it a little more flexible.

My question is mainly around (3): how do I bundle up the 7 `geom`s necessary to make the breaks into a single procedure or `geom`?

If I do this:

```
calendar_tetris_geoms <- function() {
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ymin, yend=ymax)) +                    # (a)
    geom_segment(aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=y, yend=y)) +                  # (b)
    geom_segment(aes(x=dec.x, xend=dec.x, y=dec.ymin, yend=dec.ymax)) +  # (c)
    geom_segment(aes(x=nye.xmin, xend=nye.xmax, y=nye.y, yend=nye.y)) +  # (d)
    geom_segment(x=-0.5, xend=51.5, y=7.5, yend=7.5) +                   # put a line along the top
    geom_segment(x=0.5, xend=52.5, y=0.5, yend=0.5) +                    # put a line along the bottom
    geom_text(aes(x=month.x, y=month.y, label=month.l), hjust=0.25)      # (e)

}
```

And then try to add that to my `ggplot`, it doesn't work:

```
> ggplot(data) + calendar_tetris_geoms()
Error in calendar_tetris_geoms() : 
  argument "plot" is missing, with no default
```

I clearly don't understand how this works. How does this work?

Comment: @TylerRinker the gist i provided pulls data from yahoo finance. can you use that?

Comment: use `list(geom1, geom2, geom3)` instead of `geom1+geom2+...`

Comment: @baptiste can you elaborate?

Comment: `qplot(1:10,1:10) + list(geom_point(), geom_line(), geom_step())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying @baptiste's suggestion, if I do this:

```
calendar_tetris_geoms <- function() {
  list(
    geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ymin, yend=ymax)),                 # (a)
    geom_segment(aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=y, yend=y)),                 # (b)
    geom_segment(aes(x=dec.x, xend=dec.x, y=dec.ymin, yend=dec.ymax)), # (c)
    geom_segment(aes(x=nye.xmin, xend=nye.xmax, y=nye.y, yend=nye.y)), # (d)
    geom_segment(x=-0.5, xend=51.5, y=7.5, yend=7.5),                  # put a line along the top
    geom_segment(x=0.5, xend=52.5, y=0.5, yend=0.5),                   # put a line along the bottom
    geom_text(aes(x=month.x, y=month.y, label=month.l), hjust=0.25)    # (e)
  )
}
```

Then this works a treat:

```
calendar_tetris_data(min(stock.data$date), max(stock.data$date)) %>% 
  left_join(stock.data) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=week, y=wday2factor(wday), fill = Adj.Close), colour = "white") + 
  calendar_tetris_geoms() + 
  facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Could you please share full working example of the code you have posted? I mean with sample data. I was not able to generate heatmap. Following the links you provide I got not nearer to the solution. The examples are old. The link to the data in the example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078411/1903793 is already broken. I would be grateful.

Comment: Przemyslaw, the keys to getting this to work is to have one row per day, if your data isn't, you can summarize with: newdf<-as.data.frame(table(df$date));
names(newdf)<-c("date", "n")  . To have a date field named "date" and in this format: df$date<-as.Date(df$originaldate, format='%Y-%m-%d') ; and  in geom-tile, to set "fill = n" to the field in your data that you want to color the calendar with.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019-08-06 - Pulling everything into one post to make a **Tetris Calendar Heat Map**

#### Sample date data.

This is a stand in for your date data.

```
mydatedata<-as.Date(paste(sample(c(2018:2019), 3000, replace = TRUE), # year
                          sample(c(1:12),      3000, replace = TRUE), # month
                          sample(c(1:28),      3000, replace = TRUE), # day
                          sep="-"))
```

#### Create a data frame summarizing your data

Replace `mydatedata` with your `df$date` field.

```
newdf<-as.data.frame(table(mydatedata), stringsAsFactors = FALSE); 
names(newdf)<-c("date", "n")
newdf$date<-as.Date(newdf$date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

#### Create Calendar Tetris Data Functions

Note: I created a weekday label, renamed several functions to avoid name collision, and moved the the helper functions inside the main function.

Original source links:

1)  https://gist.github.com/dvmlls/5f46ad010bea890aaf17

2)  [calendar heat map tetris chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000131/calendar-heat-map-tetris-chart/27001722#27001722)

```
calendar_tetris_data <- function(date_min, date_max) {

  year2 <- function(d) as.integer(format(d, '%Y'))

  wday2 <- function(d) {
    n <- as.integer(format(d, '%u'))
    ifelse(n==7, 0, n) + 1 # I want the week to start on Sunday=1, so turn 7 into 0.
  }

  wday2factor <- function(wd) factor(wd, levels=1:7, labels=c('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'))

  week2 <- function(d, year) { 
    # If January 1st is a Sunday, my weeks will start from 1 instead of 0 like the rest of them. 
    nyd <- as.Date(ISOdate(year, 1, 1))
    # So if that's the case, subtract 1. 
    as.integer(format(d, '%U')) - ifelse(wday2(nyd) == 1, 1, 0)
  }

  start <- as.Date(ISOdate(year2(min(date_min)),1,1))
  end <- as.Date(ISOdate(year2(max(date_max)), 12, 31))

  all.dates <- start + 0:as.integer(end - start, units='days')

  data.frame(date=all.dates) %>% tbl_df %>% 
    mutate(
      wday=wday2(date),
      year=year2(date),
      month=as.integer(format(date, '%m')),
      week=week2(date, year),
      day=as.integer(format(date, '%d')),
      weekday=wday2factor(wday), #20190806, adding weekday label


      # (a) put vertical lines to the left of the first week of each month
      x=ifelse(day <= 7, week - 0.5, NA),
      ymin=ifelse(day <= 7, wday - 0.5, NA),
      ymax=ifelse(day <= 7, wday + 0.5, NA),

      # (b) put a horizontal line at the bottom of the first of each month
      y=ifelse(day == 1, wday - 0.5, NA),
      xmin=ifelse(day == 1, week - 0.5, NA),
      xmax=ifelse(day == 1, week + 0.5, NA),

      # (c) in december, put vertical lines to the right of the last week
      dec.x=ifelse(month==12 & day >= 25, week + 0.5, NA),
      dec.ymin=ifelse(month==12 & day >= 25, wday - 0.5, NA),
      dec.ymax=ifelse(month==12 & day >= 25, wday + 0.5, NA),

      # (d) put a horizontal line at the top of New Years Eve
      nye.y=ifelse(month==12 & day == 31, wday + 0.5, NA),
      nye.xmin=ifelse(month==12 & day == 31, week - 0.5, NA),
      nye.xmax=ifelse(month==12 & day == 31, week + 0.5, NA),

      # (e) put the first letter of the month on the first day
      month.x=ifelse(day == 1, week, NA),
      month.y=ifelse(day == 1, wday, NA),
      month.l=ifelse(day == 1, substr(format(date, '%B'), 1, 3), NA)
    )
}
```

#### Create the ggplot2 geom:

```
calendar_tetris_geoms <- function() {
  list(
    geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=ymin, yend=ymax)),                 # (a)
    geom_segment(aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=y, yend=y)),                 # (b)
    geom_segment(aes(x=dec.x, xend=dec.x, y=dec.ymin, yend=dec.ymax)), # (c)
    geom_segment(aes(x=nye.xmin, xend=nye.xmax, y=nye.y, yend=nye.y)), # (d)
    geom_segment(x=-0.5, xend=51.5, y=7.5, yend=7.5),                  # put a line along the top
    geom_segment(x=0.5, xend=52.5, y=0.5, yend=0.5),                   # put a line along the bottom
    geom_text(aes(x=month.x, y=month.y, label=month.l), hjust=0.25)    # (e)
  )
}
```

#### Create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) # for %>% pipe


calendar_tetris_data(min(newdf$date), max(newdf$date)) %>% 
  left_join(newdf) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(aes(x=week, y=weekday, fill = n), colour = "white") + 
    calendar_tetris_geoms() + 
    facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 1)
```